# VSCode C# formatting - empty line after open brace and dictonaries not on same line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, format

Having an issue with formatting in VSCode and C#. I cannot find a way to put a blank line after open braces for names spaces or classes.

Also not sure how to fix the one line formatting of dictonaries so it is easier to read.

I have C# Fix Format already installed and have messed with the options. Also tried messing with Omnisharp config file but couldn't get that to work at all.

I think I am missing something. Very new to C# still.

Current formatting

```
static class MorseCodeTranslator {
    private static Dictionary<char, string> _textToMorse = new Dictionary<char, string> { { 'A', ".-" }
    };
}
```

Desired formatting

```
static class MorseCodeTranslator {

    private static Dictionary<char, string> _textToMorse = new Dictionary<char, string> {
        { 'A', ".-" }
    };

}
```

Comment: The C# visual studio editor doesn't like old fashion c language syntax putting an open curly bracket at the end of the line. Every time I do it the editor put the curly bracket on a new line.

Comment: C# Fix Format can handle that for in VSCode `"csharpfixformat.style.braces.onSameLine": true` is the option for that.

Comment: @jdweng There's a formatting option for that in visual studio (tools -> options -> text editor -> c# -> formatting -> new lines). But I don't think there's one for adding whitespace around curley brackets.